# ember test throw error - Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined

Tags: ember.js

i have migrated ember 3.16 to 3.24 
I struck on ember test error. But the app works fine

```
Chrome 88.0 - [17 ms] - Unit | Service | preferences: it exists
    ---
        actual: >
            null
        stack: >
            TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined
                at Class.setup (https://localhost:4221/assets/vendor.js:41026:134)
                at Class.setupEventDispatcher (https://localhost:4221/assets/vendor.js:42523:18)
                at Class._bootSync (https://localhost:4221/assets/vendor.js:42447:14)
                at https://localhost:4221/assets/vendor.js:45731:77
                at initializePromise (https://localhost:4221/assets/vendor.js:74537:7)
                at new Promise (https://localhost:4221/assets/vendor.js:75038:35)
                at Class.boot (https://localhost:4221/assets/vendor.js:45731:27)
                at https://localhost:4221/assets/test-support.js:3656:65
                at invokeCallback (https://localhost:4221/assets/vendor.js:74510:17)
                at https://localhost:4221/assets/vendor.js:74575:26
        message: >
            Promise rejected before "it exists": Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined
        negative: >
            false
        browser log:
```

Comment: can you please share your test and your test target?

Comment: All the test shows same error.
Please follow up below link too.
https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-test-throw-error-cannot-read-property-tagname-of-undefined/18658/3

Comment: What if you just let one test, where you know the component(s) used?